# Question on combinatorics telling the difference between distribution and division

Tags: combinatorics

$\bf{Problem}$ A double-decker bus carry $(u+l)$ passengers, $u$ in the upper deck and $l$ in the lower deck. Find the number of ways in which the $u + l$ passengers can be distributed in the two decks, if $r (\leqslant l)$ particular passengers refuse to go in the upper deck and $s(\leqslant u)$ refuse to sit in the lower deck.

**My Approach :**

Since $s$ particular persons are fixed to sit in the upper deck and *r* particular persons are fixed to sit in the lower deck therefore we need to select *(u-s)* persons from the remaining *(u+l-r-s)* persons in $^{u+l-r-s}C_{u-s}$ ways and arranging them in $(u!\cdot l!)$ ways therefore answer should be *($^{u+l-r-s}C_{u-s}$.u!.l!)*.

**Answer given in book:**
$^{u+l-r-s}C_{u-s}$

> I think the word distributed means arrangement but in the answer it has just given selection

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://www.doubtnut.com/question-answer/a-double-decker-bus-carry-u-l-passengers-u-in-the-upper-deck-and-l-in-the-lower-deck-find-the-number-31101 I don't think so but you can have a check

Comment: Your work looks correct to me, I think it is just that you had a different idea of what a "distribution" was, which is a pretty subjective wording. To be more precise they probably should have said "neglecting order" or something similar.